# How to update a cart total summary when a product gets removed from the cart

Tags: javascript

I am new to Ionic and currently working on an eCommerce app. I have successfully displayed the products added to a cart page and now need to implement the logic for deducting a relevant amount from the total summary if a product gets removed from the cart.

**This is my cart.ts**

```
removeFromCart(index,item){
    this.totalPrice = 0;
    let sumTotal = 0;
    let price = item.price;
    let qty = item.quantity
    sumTotal = price * qty;
    this.cartData.splice(index,1);
    let pId = item.id;
    this.storage.remove(`product_${pId}`).then(()=>{
    this.totalPrice -= sumTotal
    });
  }
```

**This sum up products in the cart**

```
calculatePrice(){
      this.totalPrice = 0;
      let tempPrice = 0;
      this.baseProducts.forEach((product) => {
      tempPrice = product.price * product.quantity;
      this.totalPrice += tempPrice
      });
    return this.totalPrice;
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? From what I see `this.totalPrice` is always `0` or negative value. Perhaps you want `this.totalPrice = this.calculatePrice()`?

Comment: I want the deleted product price to be removed from the total summary, for example, two products A and B with a price of $5.00 and $6.00. the total summary of the products is $11 when A  is deleted from the cart, the total summary will be $6.00. This is what i want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but did you look at what I said? Your total price is always starting off at 0

Comment: Please can you help me out